# How to access to user's phonebook in a mobile web-based app?

Tags: javascript, mobile, jquery-mobile

Is there a Javascript framework that allowed to access to user's phonebook contacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such API developed but you can use [PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts). This helps you fetch phone contacts.

Answer (score 1):

As a convention, browsers do not have permission to work with native device APIs due to security issues.

To achieve it, you have to use middle-platform such as Phonegap.

http://phonegap.com/

Comment: PhoneGap is for making native apps, so the user will have to go to the appropriate app store and download the app.

Comment: yep, as far as I know that's the only way to be able to work with native APIs